# Silent Install PFX into the Andorid System Trusted CA User Keystore

Tags: java, android, ssl-certificate, x509, pfx

My company is developing a kiosk using an android tablet. We are using TLS to communicate to a private server.  We have the Platform keys to give our client Apps system privileges. The server will only allow clients to connect if they connect using an authorized client certificate. For manufacturing the tablet, we need to load the client certificate and private key, in PFX format, into the Android System Trusted CA User keystore. Multiple apps will need to retrieve the PrivateKey and Certificate chain from the User keystore. Our manufacturing process is an automated process and does not have people available to click Yes and OK to screen prompts. We also need the silent certificate install process for replacing the client certificates as they expire in the future.

How can a PFX file be loaded into the System Trusted CA User store silently, without user interaction, from a Platform Signed App?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible only for enterprise wifi configuration only. The following method will configure the WPA/EAP-TLS wifi configuration with CA certificate and User certificate.

```
public static void createEapConfig(Context context, String ssid, String password, boolean connectAutomatically, boolean hiddenNetwork,
                                   Integer eapMethod, Integer phase2, String identity, String anonymousIdentity, String caCertificateData,
                                   String clientCertificateData, String clientCertPass) {
    if (ssid == null || eapMethod == null) {
        return;
    }
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    boolean connect = connectAutomatically;
    boolean isWifiReceiverRegistered = false;
    try {
        Logger.logEnteringOld();

        WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();
        config.SSID = "\"" + ssid + "\"";
        config.hiddenSSID = hiddenNetwork;//false; //hidden network is always set to false.
        config.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
        config.priority = 40;
        try {
            wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class).invoke(wifiManager, config, false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.logError(e);
        }
        Settings.isWifiHotspotEnabled(false);
        if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }

        if (connect) {
            lastActNetId = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId();
            wifiManager.disableNetwork(lastActNetId);
            wifiManager.disconnect();
        }
        config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);
        config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X);

        // Set defaults
        if (phase2 == null) phase2 = WifiEnterpriseConfig.Phase2.NONE;
        if (identity == null) identity = "";
        if (anonymousIdentity == null) anonymousIdentity = "";
        if (caCertificateData == null) caCertificateData = "";
        if (clientCertificateData == null) clientCertificateData = "";
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
            if (Util.isNullOrEmpty(password)) {
                config.enterpriseConfig.setPassword(password);
            }

            config.enterpriseConfig.setEapMethod(eapMethod);

            if (phase2 != null) {
                config.enterpriseConfig.setPhase2Method(phase2);
            }
            if (!Util.isNullOrEmpty(identity)) {
                config.enterpriseConfig.setIdentity(identity);
            }
            if (!Util.isNullOrEmpty(anonymousIdentity)) {
                config.enterpriseConfig.setAnonymousIdentity(anonymousIdentity);
            }
            InputStream is = null;
            if (!Util.isNullOrEmpty(caCertificateData)) {
                try {
                    byte[] decodedCaCert = Base64.decode(caCertificateData);
                    //is = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/local-root(1).cer" );
                    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
                    try {

                        is = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedCaCert);
                        X509Certificate caCert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(is);
                        config.enterpriseConfig.setCaCertificate(caCert);
                    } catch (CertificateException ex) {
                        Logger.logError(ex);
                    } finally {
                        if (is != null) {
                            is.close();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    Logger.logError(t);
                }
            }
            if (!Util.isNullOrEmpty(clientCertificateData) && !Util.isNullOrEmpty(clientCertPass)) {
                try {
                    byte[] decodedClientCert = Base64.decode(clientCertificateData);
                    KeyStore p12 = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
                    is = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedClientCert);
                    //is = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/createdDERCert(1).pfx");
                    p12.load(is, clientCertPass.toCharArray());
                    Enumeration aliases = p12.aliases();
                    for (String alias : Collections.list(aliases)) {

                        if (alias == null) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) p12.getKey(alias, clientCertPass.toCharArray());
                        if (privateKey == null) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        X509Certificate clientCert = (X509Certificate) p12.getCertificate(alias);

                        if (clientCert != null) {
                            config.enterpriseConfig.setClientKeyEntry(privateKey, clientCert);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    Logger.logError(t);
                } finally {
                    if (is != null) {
                        try {
                            is.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        int networkId = -1;
        networkId = wifiManager.addNetwork(config);

        wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true);
        wifiManager.saveConfiguration();

        if (connect) {
            wifiManager.reconnect();
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
            Settings.cntxt.registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, filter);
            isWifiReceiverRegistered = true;
            Thread.sleep(15000);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        if (NetworkStateReceiver.activeConnection(Settings.cntxt)) {
            lastActNetId = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.logError(ex);
    } finally {
        // unregister wifi state receiver
        if (connect && isWifiReceiverRegistered) {
            isWifiReceiverRegistered = false;
            Settings.cntxt.unregisterReceiver(wifiReceiver);
        }
    }

    Logger.logEnteringOld();
}
```